# backbone save to server parse.com

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

i'm using backbone method save to update user object on parse.com. object that in backbone are based on a model and collection. When i fetch it's all right but when save appear: PUT https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/xj3QLLYy07 400 (Bad Request)

{"code":206,"error":"Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError"}

Model:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/",

    idAttribute: "objectId",

    defaults:{
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log("inperson");
        // this.upload();
    }

});

return Person;
```

Collection:

```
var Usercollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Person,

    url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/',

    parse: function(data) {
        return data.results;
    }

});

return Usercollection;
```

and the code where i try to save the model:

```
this.model.save({email:"ciao@lib.it"}, {
    // wait:true,
    success:function(model, response) {
        console.log('Successfully saved!');
    },
    error: function(model, error) {
        console.log(model.toJSON());
        console.log(error.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: (Deleted my answer is it is more conjecture than anything): Try removing the trailing slash on your ``url`` property:

Comment: the url is ok,it's works also when i use save on a new modelù(save on parse perfectly),the problem is how to update a fetched model

Comment: You fetched model will be available in the `success` callback.. Where in the first argument is the model that was sent from the server.. If you are talking in terms of a View you can always bind the `sync` event so that the view invokes some method when the model is updated

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer needs an update. Cant you just swap the backbone collection and model to Parse's ones?

[Here is a short example that worked for me today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357485/connection-between-model-and-collection-in-backbone-and-parse-com/31688130#31688130)